# iOS Safari focus not triggering on tap

Tags: css, focus, ios9, accessibility, mobile-safari

This is an issue with iOS9 Safari. The `:focus` styling is not triggering when a `button` or anchor tag is tapped, not even the native focus outlines.

To investigate the issue, I have tried adding a listener for the focus event on the button, but it's not triggering on tap. It does, however, triggers when the focus event is manually triggered with `.focus()`. Here is a screencast of what I have tried: [iOS Safari Missing focus event](https://www.screencast.com/t/FAAt5IedW)

Is this an expected behaviour for iOS Safari? Don't they require focus event? I thought it was essential for accessibility? I cannot resort into using `:active`, cause it does not behave according to my needs.

Comment: can you provide a link, or a code example? could help a lot supporting you to fix this problem!